# Ubuntu XAMPP error_log file cleaning

Tags: apache2, installation, xampp, ubuntu-12.04, error-log

I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have XAMPP installed on it. From couple of days, Ubuntu sending errors like you have some XX MB left on disk. When I examine I find the error_log file in XAMPP installation contains 1 GB of my disk. So, I like to ask whether it is safe to delete logs in that file, or it will harm to my XAMPP installation. And if it will harm for installation, how should I remove those logs with safe way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's name says the error_log file logs apache errors, so if you are in a production environment you may want to backup this file before deleting logs.

after the backup is done simply empty the file :

```
cat /dev/null > /path/to/your/xampp/apache/error_log
```

1GB of log is quite huge you may change the LogLevel value in your apache configurations files.

Regards

mimiz